# Is BizTalk feasible for generating an nightly xml File?

Tags: c#, winforms, biztalk

My team is planning to use Biztalk server 2006. The task is as follows:-

Run a scheduled job every night which fetches from multiple databases a set of data (basically the same select query with a where clause run for about 20000 Id's) and writes it into an xml file.

Presently we have c# winform which does the same for one or multiple Id on user input. But the customer does not want user input and instead wants to run a job in the night, so that in the morning the xml contains the latest data from all the databases.

We thought Biztalk is good as we will require good fault handling and no loss of data. And also because its a good experience for us as we have never used Biztalk. (We have a license already for another project in the same department)

Please advise, is Biztalk the solution?

Comment: Biztalk 2006? not the most recent version?

Comment: I'd write a CLR stored procedure or even a TSQL stored procedure and schedule it...

Comment: @mitch :ya not the latest, we still have biztalk 2006. We could write a sp and schedule it, but we were wondering if biztalk could do it better. Also the integration with other systems is bound to grow for this tool

Comment: The only benefit you would get from BizTalk is the extensive tracking and monitoring of your process. Given the rather simple requirement you would add a lot of overhead - which your customer may not want to pay for. If this specific requirement is part of a bigger integration scenario it would allow you start out with a reliable infrastructure.

Answer (score 3):

In the winforms app you already have the C# code to do the transfer. In this case there does not appear to be any business value in moving this one process to Biztalk.

You could move this code to a windows service app, that would automatically run each night.

To make it more robust, I would first copy all data to a temporary table, then process it one row at a time, making sure that everyting is saved after each row. Then if something crashes it will start where it left off last time.

Answer (score 2):

As per Mitch, it would be a stretch to go and buy, install and learn BizTalk to use it to poll databases and extract XML files.

However, if you already have BizTalk in your enterprise, and a policy to use it for all Integration, and that you regard your XML extraction as integration, well, OK.

It is pretty simple:

- Use the appropriate adapter to poll
  your data (e.g. SQL Adapter if your
  RDBMS's are SQL, DB2 on the HIS pack,
  etc). For MSSQL `FOR XML AUTO` is the
  easiest way to get it into any sort
  of XML
- You'll need to define schemas for input and output XML
- Create a Map (or maps) to convert the SQL result set into the required file format.
- Use a simple file adapter as the send port to do the XML write.

Use the Receive Port's Schedule / Service Window to restrict the timing to once per night.

One gotcha : when polling the SQL database, block concurrent access to the data (e.g. use an UPDLOCK) or similar to ensure that if the job is fired concurrently that it won't duplicate the file output.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Well, ya as u say its not really integration, you could say that we are primarily doing it for learning purposes. We have the winform now to fetch data from the db's but that requires manual input and also it writes only one row into the xml on one user input. Can we embed a winform app into the biztalk orchestration and use that for fetching and writing, the biztalk will only handle timing, error and repeat and concurrent access.

Comment: @srivatsayb - No, that doesn't sound like a good idea - BizTalk and app UI don't really mix. Since as you say you are doing it for learning purposes, get your hands dirty with creating schemas, maps, ports and possibly an orchestration.